# Bootstrap 5 error: "$(...).carousel is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I know there are a lot of other questions like this one, but I have tried every single solution I have seen with no luck.

1)Jquery is loaded before bootstrap
2)Bootstrap libraries are up to date
3)As far as I can tell, bootstrap.min.js is loading properly and I even switched it to a CDN delivery instead of loading it locally just to make sure the versions weren't mismatched or some other weird issue.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>HOME</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "customstyle/research_styles.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "customstyle/navbar.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-black">
           <a class = "navbar-brand" class = "typewriter_welcome" href = "#"><p class = "typewriter_welcome">Wang Lab</p></a>
           <button class = "navbar-toggler" type = "button" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls = "navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded = "false" aria-label = "Toggle Navigation">
               <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
           <div class = "collaspse navbar-collapse" id = "navbarNav">
               <ul class = "navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                   <li class = "nav-item active">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "index.html">Home<span class = "sr-only"></span></a>
                   </li>
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "research.html">Research (Current)</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">Publications</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">Patents</a>
                   </li>              
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">News</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">Photos</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">Collaborations</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">People</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class = "nav-item">
                       <a class = "nav-link" href = "#">Contact</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </nav>

       <div class = "fold"></div>

       <div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/molecule.jpeg" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/parkinsons.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/MRI.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <script type = "text/javascript"> $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 2000});</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, load your stylesheets before the scripts

Comment: have you tried changing carousel to owlCarousel
......
<script type = "text/javascript"> $('.carousel').owlCarousel({interval: 2000});</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues. You should refer to the [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/).

1. jQuery is no longer required for Bootstrap 5, but if you want to use it, it should be placed before bootstrap.js and the end of the body tag (not in the head).
2. The `data-` attributes are now `data-bs-` in Bootstrap 5
3. Wait for the DOM to be ready!

```
$(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 2000})
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/PvIFpr3XhG)

Answer (score 0):

Carousel is defined in `bootstrap.js`

Instead of loading the bundle, try this instead:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately.

Comment: Is there something weird with the javascript needing to be loaded before the css? That wouldn't make any sense to me but I'm kind of at my wits end here.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap 5 options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#options), you can change the interval via data attributes `<div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="1000">`. Also, see other comments, some syntax has changed in 5.